# Native Query with PostGIS Throws HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, hibernate-spatial

I have two queries in my Spring Data JPA repository, one written in JPQL and another in native SQL. The JPQL query works flawlessly, while the native query throws a HttpMessageNotWritableException. Both queries are nearly identical in terms of the selected fields and conditions.

Here are the queries:

Native Query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT " +
        "o.geometry\\:\\:geometry as geometry, " +
        "o.center\\:\\:geometry as center, " +
        "FROM overlay as o " +
        "JOIN company_layer as cl on cl.id = o.layer_id " +
        "WHERE o.ts_overlaytext @@ to_tsquery(:searchString) AND o.disabled = false",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<MyProjection> findWithNativeQuery(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

JPQL Query:

```
@Query("SELECT " +
        "o.geometry as geometry, " +
        "o.center as center, " +
        "FROM Overlay o " +
        "WHERE o.layer.id = :layerId AND o.disabled = false AND o.layer.company.id = :companyId")
List<MyProjection> findWithJPQLQuery(@Param("layerId") Long layerId, @Param("companyId") Long companyId);
```

Both queries aim to select data from the Overlay entity, and the only significant difference is the usage of native SQL in the first one.

The JPQL query works as expected, but when I execute the native query, and try to send data to the frontend from the controller, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Cannot project org.geolatte.geom.Polygon to org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found
```

What could be causing this issue specifically in the context of the native query?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Internally Hibernate Spatial uses the Geolatte library for spatial/geometry types. Your domain model uses JTS, however. For JPQL, Hibernate will automatically translate to JTS. It can do that because it has knowledge of the application model. In the case of a native query, this information is not available and Spring Data simply assumes that what is returned by Hibernate is of the appropriate type.